# How do I access and modify __list_of_hospital_lab_test_ids in class LabTestRepository?

Tags: python, oop

```
class LabTestRepository:
       __list_of_hospital_lab_ids = [ 'L101', 'L102' , 'L102' ]
```

Because when I access it directly using `LabTestRepository.__list_of_hospital_lab_ids` I get an error:

> AttributeError : type object 'LabTestRepository' has no attribute '__list_of_hospital_lab_ids'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)

Comment: In that case, it is `LabTestRepository._LabTestRepository__list_of_hospital_lab_ids`.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't *supposed* to access class' attributes that start with two underscores (and don't end with two underscores) from *outside* that class. This is a bit similar to `private` class members in C++, for example: there you have *no way* of accessing such attributes, but Python doesn't have this exact mechanism, but it has the one described above, which works similarly, but still *does* let you access such attributes, but in an obscure manner:

```
>>> class Test:
...     __data = 5
...     
>>> Test.__data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Test' has no attribute '__data'
>>> dir(Test)
['_Test__data', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
>>> Test._Test__data
5
```

As you can see, the name of the attribute `__data` has been changed to `_Test__data`, but one can still access it. The same thing happens in your code. In general, the real name of such double-underscored attribute will be changed to `_ClassName__AttributeName`.

In your case that would be `LabTestRepository._LabTestRepository__list_of_hospital_lab_ids`.

---

As you can see, this doesn't apply to attributes with two underscores both at the beginning and the end, however:

```
>>> class Test:
...     def __test__():
...         print('hello')
...         
>>> Test.__test__()
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to access private variable of class. hence you need to do:

```
LabTestRepository._LabTestRepository__list_of_hospital_lab_ids
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python attributes with doubled underscore at the begging means "private". But you can get access to them with some trick:

```
LabTestRepository._LabTestRepository__list_of_hospital_lab_ids
```